# How can I Re-training the AutlML model in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-nl

I have trained and deployed a Natural Language model on Google Cloud Vertex AI(Auto ML) with about 50,000 records data.
Now I have additional about 3,000 records data.
How can I re-train the existing model with 3,000 data?
Or should I train a new model with 53,000 data?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible to load new data in **any** trained Machine Learning model. Unfortunately, if you want to contemplate the new data, you will need to train it all together.

When you are creating the model from scratch, there exists the possibility of [training the model](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28512/train-new-data-to-pre-trained-model?rq=1) based in your previous one, but in black box applications such as Cloud Vertex AI, the logic behind the model is inaccessible for the customer.

I recommend this [lecture](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12761/should-a-model-be-re-trained-if-new-observations-are-available) of tips about when a model should be trained when new data is available.

Additionally, in  some products such as AutoML Vision there exists a feature for [resumable training](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/train?hl=en#resumable_training) which allows you to pause and resume model training for large datasets. If you are interested in implementing this feature for Vertex AI, I would suggest you to open a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try to train new model with all data.