# How to retrain the existing vertex AI model using more data? Is there any process with python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai, automl, google-prediction

I am learning Google's vertex AI, AutoML with Python. I have created the single label dataset, pipelines, endpoint and deployed the model using google's UI.

Now I have more data then how to append that into existing dataset? or retrain the existing model?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to update a model with new data, the only way as of now is to create a new dataset and train a new model on it. As mentioned in this **[stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67737032/18329678)**, it is not possible to load new data in any trained Machine Learning model. For more information you can refer to the above **[stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67737032/18329678).**

However, you can file a Feature Request on the **[issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers),** if you are interested in the implementation of this feature.